# linq to xml, handling empty tags

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

The following link statement works fine if the source XML contains a number or if the tags are missing. The problem I have is when the tags are empty or if a non-numeric value is used. Can this statement be modified to handle these situations ?

```
Convert.ToInt32((string)Data.Elements("groupBy").Elements("depth").FirstOrDefault() ?? "0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know of a way to solve this with LINQ but if you cannot guarantee the content of the XML document then would it be easier to just use int.TryParse()?, e.g.

```
int result = 0;
int.TryParse((string)Data.Elements("groupBy").Elements("depth").FirstOrDefault(), out result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
try
    int result = (int)Data.Elements("groupBy").Elements("depth").FirstOrDefault();
catch
{
    // handle
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this is one of several commands creating an object (part of a “select new myClass” statement) so adding a try catch won’t work. I know I didn’t give all the details in my question as I wanted to modify the individual line of code.